# How to access objects of exported functions for unit testing using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

How to access objects of exported functions for unit testing using jest(node JS) Basically I'm looking for a way to access objects of exported functions and test them
Please help

```
//function.js
async function createTempUsageStatisticsTable(athenaExpress) {
let athenaQueryParam = {
    sql: getSqlQueries.CREATE_DEVICE_USAGE_STATS_TEMP_TABLE_QUERY,
    db: "testdb"
};
try {
    await athenaExpress.query(athenaQueryParam);
}
catch (error) {
    console.error;
}
}
module.exports = {
  createTempUsageStatisticsTable: createTempUsageStatisticsTable
};

//function.test.js
const index = require('./function')
//require a test to check if sql has 
//getSqlQueries.CREATE_DEVICE_USAGE_STATS_TEMP_TABLE_QUERY

//require a 2nd test to check if db is testdb
```

Comment: What's there to test? That function doesn't really *do* anything.

Comment: I am already returning something from my function test1() to perform a certain action.... so i cant really return a object aswell as that might break what my function is supposed to do

Comment: Then why do you care what's in the object? What's the *point* of the object? Give a less abstract example.

Comment: Apologies...Posted actual code to clarify why i need to check for object properties

Comment: Then you don't need to test what's in the object, that's an implementation detail, but *what the collaborator is called with*. Also I think you're missing at least one `}` and that's not how you actually *use* console.error.

Comment: Thanks,Fixed the bracket issue.... what i want is when control goes to catch block it should throw an error and that function should fail should i use throw error instead ?

Comment: In that case just don't use try at all - don't catch the error if you're not going to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass query as jest.mock and verify it's called value should be what is expected.
//function.test.js

```
const index=require('./function')
test('expect value', () => {
  const mockAthenaExpress = {
    query: jest.fn()
  }
  const testObj = index. createTempUsageStatisticsTable(mockAthenaExpress);
  expect(mockAthenaExpress.query.mock.calls[0][0].db).toEqual('testdb');
})
```

Comment: I am already returning something from my function test1() to perform a certain action.... so i cant really return a object aswell as that might break what my function is supposed to do

Comment: if you can't return that object then you can't test value of that variable because that is local variable of that function.

Comment: Posted actual code please check if there is anyway to test without comprimising functionality ?

Comment: updated answer. you can pass query as jest.mock and verify if your query function is called with correct arguments